# Fixed frame does not exist on Rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i have a problem on rviz, fixed frame not existe. do you have any solution of tutorial for create fixed frame please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232912/fixed-frame-does-not-exist-on-rviz/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look for a link in [rviz fixed frame does not exist](http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/page:1/query:rviz%20fixed%20frame%20%22does%20not%20exist%22/) that has a 1 or more answer and a green check mark on it.

(Is there a way to make the answer to the question a sticky post on the top of the answers.ros.org front page?)

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-26**:\

> Is there a way to make the answer to the question a sticky post

Would be nice :). But it would also be nice if people would use the search and / or read the RViz documentation. That would save us a lot of questions like this one.